# Is there a word for a place you've already been?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a particular word (slang or not) or perhaps a phrase that describes a location or place you've already visited?

Comment: Been there, done that.

Comment: That's all *known territory*

Comment: *visited*, noun : "the act or **an instance of visiting**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All the old familiar places"
has [a page all of its own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I'll_Be_Seeing_You_(song),  But since the phrase has been appropriated, not to say subverted, by the Joker, **'haunts'** might be a better choice

> plural noun: **haunts** (This is the Google response)
>
> ```
> 1.
> a place frequented by a specified person.
> "the bar was a favourite haunt of artists of the time"
> synonyms: hang-out, stamping ground, meeting place,  
> territory, domain, purlieu, resort,
> ```

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/haunt) gives both verb (haunt) and noun (haunt / haunts)

> **haunt**  (verb)  Collins Dictionary
>    to visit (a place) frequently
>
> also  (noun)
>
> (often plural) a place visited frequently   *"an old haunt of hers"*

Comment: A haunt is a place that you have visited often.  The question doesn't necessarily require that.

Comment: @Chenmunka, you could be right.

Comment: ah, by the acceptance of this answer I will assume they had meant someplace often visited as opposed to the singular visit implied in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [**Sojourned**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sojourn) or **[Toured](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tour#tour__13)**

From the **Oxford Dictionary**

> **Sojourn** - Stay somewhere temporarily:
>   i.e. *she had sojourned in Egypt*
>
> **Tour** - A short trip to or through a place in order to view or inspect something, A journey for pleasure in which several different places are visited,
>   i.e. *they had toured in a little minivan*

Answer (score 0):

Of places that I had visited often in the past, I refer to them as my ***stomping grounds***. This would generally refer to the area around the university I attended, where I spent summer vacations regularly, or where I grew up.